# workflow email notification

Tags: email, workflow, email-alert

In workflow -> Email notification (I want to set the below format, I am unable to set the NEW STAGE)

> Dear "Approver"
>
> "Opportunity Owner" made a change to "Opportunity Name".
>
> The Opportunity Stage was changed from "Old Stage" to "New Stage"

Comment: Hi Sachin, You can edit the Email template and achieve the above.

Comment: Hi Anitha, i am unable to set the OLD STAGE. Eg : Now current Opp Stage is (1) Available, user has changed the Opp Stage -> Available to (4) Close. At that time email notification will be send to the Manager. Like The Opportunity Stage was changed from "Old Stage (1) Available" to "New Stage (4) Close".

Comment: You can't have old value in workflow like in triggers. Better option is to send this email using triggers, where you can have old values as well.

Comment: Hi Abbas, could you please share the code ?

Answer (score 0):

Below Trigger works fine for sending email via triggers.

```
    trigger StageOpp_trg on Opportunity (after update)

{


String body;String [] toAddress=new String[]{};//Add the to address/approver email address
String stageold,stagenew;
for(Integer i=0;i<Trigger.Old.size();i++)
{
Opportunity op1=Trigger.old[i];
Opportunity op2=Trigger.new[i];

if(op1.StageName!=op2.StageName)
{
stageold=op1.StageName;
stagenew=op2.StageName;
toAddress.add('xxxx@test.com');
body='Dear Approver, Opportunity Owner : '+op2.Owner+'</br>'+'made a change to Name:'+op2.Name+'Opportunity Stage:'+stageold+'is changed to'+
'Opportunity New Stage:'+stagenew;//Customize it by adding </br>.
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email=new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
email.setToAddresses(toAddress);
email.setHTMLBody(body);
Messaging.SendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[]{email});
System.debug('success');
}
}

}
```

Thanks.